# keras > always the same prediction value after loading saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training some model via `keras` with `tensorflow` backend.

When I call predict right after training on the same object it works fine and gives different values for different inputs. But when I save the model to a file, then load it from another `python` session, `predict` always returns the same value for different inputs.

I use `ModelCheckpoint` for saving the model, then `load_model` for loading. I have also tried to save and load architecture separately to a json file with `to_json` and `model_from_json` functions. Sample code:

Saving part

```
with open("model.json", "w") as textFile:
   print(model.to_json(), file = textFile)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=iterationCount, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.h5', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)])
```

Loading part

```
with open('model.json') as json_file:
    model = model_from_json(json_file.read())

model.load_weights('model.h5')
```

Any ideas to solve this? Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Could you disable the `save_best_only` option and check if anything changes.

Comment: How about data preprocessing? Is it the same? If data is not scaled it's very often that you'll obtain the same prediction for all examples.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Yes, for preprocessing I use scikit learn's `StandardScaler()`. I save and load the scaler in a file with `joblib.dump()` and `joblib.load()` functions.

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue and I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko was right, there was a bug in data preprocessing code. There were very big numbers in my data and due to that bug they have not been cleared/scaled, which caused to behavior described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately many people (like me) have been complaining on a [keras bug](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2160) that affects the `save_weights` and `load_weights` functions.

I ended up avoiding to use these function. If I want to load/store my model I just do the following:

```
from keras.models import load_model

trained_model.save(file_path)
loaded_model = load_model(file_path)
```

The `save` functions saves your weights, but also your network structure and the state of the optimizer (it makes sure that you can keep training model from exactly where you paused).

Comment: I have tried to use the approach that you have mentioned, but it again gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved by setting a fixed seed to tensorflow, numpy and python.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random as python_random
tf.random.set_random_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
python_random.seed(42)
```

Be careful! Different versions of tensorflow may required a different way to set a seed!

Answer (score 1):

keras model save/load has two ways (two ways I feel comfortable to use). Saving both model structure and weights `model.save(file_path)` and only save model weights `model.save_weights(file_path)`.
So I save/load model like following:

```
from keras.models import load_model
trained_model.save(file_path)
loaded_model = load_model(file_path)

trained_model.save_weights(file_path)
# We have to define model first before loading weights
trained_model.load_weights(file_path)
```

Here, `load_weights(file_path, by_name=True)` allows you to load weights into a different structure with some layer names in common.